# Add minimum available key to dictionary MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, dictionary, mongodb-query

I have documents in collection which have structure:

```
{key: {0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 100, 4: 15}}
```

I need to add pair `key: value` to dictionary. `value` may be anything. It doesn’t matter. But `key` must be the smallest integer that is not used in the dictionary as a key (starts from 0).

I can do it using python.

```py
document = {key: {0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 100, 4: 15}}
new_key = 0  # key to insert in our dict
for i in range(max(document['key'].keys()) + 2):
    if i not in document['key'].keys():
        new_key = i

# update the document
document['key'][new_key] = value  # value may be anything
```

How to do it using MongoDB? Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possibility (requires `Mongo 4.2` or better):

```
// { key: { 0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 100, 4: 15 } }
db.collection.update(
  {},
  [
    { $set: {
      newkey: {
        $toString: {
          $min: {
            $setDifference: [
              { $range: [0, 10] },
              { $map: {
                input: { $objectToArray: "$key" },
                as: "x",
                in: { $toInt: "$$x.k" }
              }}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }},
    { $set: {
      key: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $concatArrays: [
            { $objectToArray: "$key" },
            [{ k: "$newkey", v: 1000 }]
          ]
        }
      }
    }},
    { $unset: "newkey" }
])
// { key: { 0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 100, 4: 15, 3: 1000 } }
```

Note that we're using an `update` with an aggregation pipeline (symbolised by the square brackets in `update({}, [...])`) which is available starting in `Mongo 4.2` and without which we can't update a document based on its own content.

The first [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#mongodb-update-up.-set) stage is there to create a temporary value which is the new key (in our case `3`) for which to add the new value:

- It starts by transforming the `key` object into an array of `{ k: "key", v: "value" }` objects for an easy access to keys (see [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/)):

  ```
  { $objectToArray: "$key" }
  // { key: [{ k: "0", v: 2 }, { k: "1", v: 5 }, { k: "2", v: 100 }, { k: "4", v: 15 }] }
  ```
- That we then transform into an array of integers out of the `k` keys (see [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [`$toInt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/)):

  ```
  { $map: { input: { ... }, as: "x", in: { $toInt: "$$x.k" } } }
  // [ 0, 1, 2, 4 ]
  ```
- That we then intersect with a range between 0 and whatever (here 10) (see [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) and [`$range`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/)):

  ```
  $setDifference: [{ $range: [0, 10] }, {...}]
  // [ 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ]
  ```

  - but if you'd rather have an upper range based on the array's max key, it's possible too): just replace `10` with:

    ```
    { $max: { $map: { input: { $objectToArray: "$key" }, as: "x", in: { $toInt: "$$x.k" } } } }
    // 4
    ```
- From which we can extract the min:

  ```
  $min: { ... }
  // 3
  ```
- That we cast to string:

  ```
  $toString: { ... }
  // "3"
  ```
- Such that the intermediate version of the document becomes:

  ```
  { key: { 0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 100, 4: 15 }, newkey: "3" }
  ```

The second `$set` stage replaces the `key` object with the existing `key` object appended with the new key value:

- It starts by, again, transforming the `key` object in an array of `{ k: "key", v: "value" }` objects:

  ```
  { $objectToArray: "$key" }
  // { key: [{ k: "0", v: 2 }, { k: "1", v: 5 }, { k: "2", v: 100 }, { k: "4", v: 15 }] }
  ```
- In order to append the new key/value through a [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) operation:

  ```
  $concatArrays: [{...}, [{ k: "$newkey", v: 1000 }]]
  // { key: [{ k: "0", v: 2 }, { k: "1", v: 5 }, { k: "2", v: 100 }, { k: "4", v: 15 }, { k: "3", v: 1000 }] }
  ```
- Array that we can finally transform back into an object (see [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)):

  ```
  $arrayToObject: { ... }
  // { 0: 2, 1: 5, 2: 100, 4: 15, 3: 1000 }
  ```

The very last stage, the `$unset` stage, is just there to remove the intermediate variable `newkey`.

Note that it's possible to plug-in the first `$set` stage within the second one, by replacing `"$newkey"` with the content of the first `$set`, but that'd be less readable, I think.